# Issue with facet_grid() including variables not apart of the grouping in r

Tags: r, facet-grid

#how do i get rid of the blank columns in the faceting?

```
    tidy_tibble %>%
ggplot() +
  aes(x = calculation,
      y = value) + #assign x and y axis, add grouping
  geom_col(fill = "blue2") + #make bar plot
  facet_grid(~ test_type) + #add faceting
  theme_bw() #change theme
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TeMu.png)

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moHl9.png)

Comment: Can you give us some of your data so we can try to reproduce the issue? Something like `dput(head(data, n = 100))`. Also, include an image of the plot produced by your code and describe what you would like it to look like instead.

Comment: `facet_grid(~ test_type, scales = "free_x")`

Comment: @BenNorris if you click on the word "plot" its hyperlinked and the pic should come up. I want both RMSE bars on one side and both Rsquared vales on the other side. there shouldn't be a blank space with their names. I will add a photo of the data as well,

Comment: @Lucy, Please do not add a photo of the data. We cannot copy and paste that into R and test your code. Give us a sample of the data, or some code to generate it. Here is more advice on making your question reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example